# Why is my # mapping behaving oddly in TeX files?

Tags: key-bindings, filetype-tex

I recently made the following key-map in my `.vimrc` file:

```
inoremap # \
inoremap \ #
```

since I just want to switch those two key on my keyboard, everything works just fine until I notice this:

1. Only in `.tex` file, when I hit the <kbd>#</kbd> key (now map to `\`), it will show as `#` for about 1 second, then if I do nothing it will change to `\`.
2. also only in `.tex` file, when I hit the <kbd>#</kbd> key and immediately hit another key, for most of the key, say <kbd>x</kbd>, although it shows `#` at first, it will change to `/x` as soon as I hit <kbd>x</kbd>. But for some key like <kbd>b</kbd>, if I do not wait it to turn to `\` (as described in (1)) before I hit <kbd>b</kbd>, it will be `#b` in the end, if I wait it to turn to `\`, then it will show as `\b`.

Any solution to this?

The following is my `.vimrc` file:

```vim
call plug#begin()

Plug 'lervag/vimtex'
Plug 'vim-scripts/AutoComplPop'
Plug 'SirVer/ultisnips'
Plug 'honza/vim-snippets'

call plug#end()

set complete+=kspell

let g:tex_flavor='latex'
let g:vimtex_view_method = 'zathura'
let g:vimtex_quickfix_mode=0
" show conceal"
set conceallevel=2
let g:tex_conceal='abdmg'

let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<tab>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<tab>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<s-tab>"

" :UltiSnipsEdit to split your window."
let g:UltiSnipsEditSplit="vertical"
let g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories=["UltiSnips", "mySnips"]

autocmd BufWinLeave *.* mkview
" autocmd BufWinEnter *.* silent loadview"

" keymap, see :help map-modes for reference"
inoremap # \
inoremap \ #

set cursorline
set cursorcolumn
set expandtab
set ts=4 sts=4 sw=4
set colorcolumn=80,120
set rnu
set ruler
syntax on


hi cursorline cterm=NONE ctermbg=237
hi cursorcolumn ctermbg=237
hi cursorlinenr cterm=NONE ctermbg=237
hi Conceal cterm=NONE ctermfg=lightyellow ctermbg=NONE
" to clear conceal highlighting use the command :hi clear Conceal"
hi ColorColumn ctermbg=240
```

Comment: You can remove the `g:tex_flavor` and `g:tex_conceal` options when you use VimTeX. They will not be relevant and would therefore only be confusing. Also, notice that `set conceallevel` is a window local option. If you want it for LaTeX it would be better to set it with an autocmd, e.g. `autocmd FileType tex setlocal conceallevel=2`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably because there's another multi-key mapping that starts with a `#`; this is added by the TeX-specific plugin you have and loaded only for those files. You can reproduce it with:

```
inoremap # \
inoremap \ #
inoremap #x Pressed #x
```

If you type just `#` Vim doesn't know if you want trigger the `#` mapping or the `#x` mapping, so it needs to wait for a bit to see which one you want, since people aren't infinitely fast typers.

Vim will wait for the second keypress for `timeoutlen` milliseconds; the default is `1000` (1 second), but you can decrease this with e.g. `set timeout=200`. This does mean you'll have to type those mapping faster (only if there's a mapping for the single keypress *and* more than one, e.g. it won't affect `g<other>`; that will just wait forever since there's no mapping for just `g`).

Pressing e.g. `#y` will insert `\y` as expected; since `#y` isn't mapped Vim knows you wanted to trigger the `#` mapping. You don't need to wait for the screen to update, but it does look a bit odd.

---

To see which mappings are set up use `:imap #`:

```
i  #x          * Pressed #x
i  #           * \
```

and add `:verbose` to see where they're set from:

```
:verbose imap #
i  #x          * Pressed #x
        Last set from ~/.vim/vimrc line 737
i  #           * \
        Last set from ~/.vim/vimrc line 734
```

---

You can probably configure your TeX plugin to not map these; I installed that plugin and got:

```
i  #B          *@vimtex#imaps#wrap_math("#B", vimtex#imaps#style_math("mathbb"))
i  #-          *@vimtex#imaps#wrap_math("#-", vimtex#imaps#style_math("overline"))
i  #c          *@vimtex#imaps#wrap_math("#c", vimtex#imaps#style_math("mathcal"))
i  #f          *@vimtex#imaps#wrap_math("#f", vimtex#imaps#style_math("mathfrak"))
i  #b          *@vimtex#imaps#wrap_math("#b", vimtex#imaps#style_math("mathbf"))
i  #/          *@vimtex#imaps#wrap_math("#/", vimtex#imaps#style_math("slashed"))
```

Which confirms that this is your issue.

Looking at the plugin documentation, there's a few options to change or disable this; `let g:vimtex_imaps_enabled = 0` will disable all insert-mode mappings, but you can also select a different "leader". Note that this disables many other insert mode mappings too (`:VimtexImapsList` has a list).

See `:help vimtex-imaps` for the full documentation on it so you can see what works well for you.

Comment: This is correct. I would also mention that it is possible to specify `<nowait>` to mappings to ignore these mapping conflicts. Thus, another option to solve this would be `nnoremap <nowait> # /` and similar for the corresponding mapping.